# Spring generically implement @Inject or @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, inject

I have one generic interface like so:

```
public interface DaoClass extends Closeable {
}
```

I have many interfaces implementing that:

```
public interface PersonDao extends DaoClass {
    Person getPerson(long personNo);
}
public interface BusinessDao extends DaoClass {
    void setAddress(long businessNo, String address);
}
```

And I have a function like this:

```
public class DaoClassFactory {
    public static <T extends DaoClass> T create(final Class<T> daoClass) {
        // custom logic to return instance of this daoClass
    }
}
```

I want to be able to have something like:

```
@Inject PersonDao personDao;
@Inject BusinessDao businessDao;
```

At the top of a `@Controller` to *just work* by calling `DaoClassFactory.create()` to create the beans, and then calling the `.close()` method on them afterwards to clean up.

Is there a generic way to do that without listing out individual factories for each type in XML?  I haven't been able to find any way.

Thanks much!

Comment: Maybe http://www.baeldung.com/simplifying-the-data-access-layer-with-spring-and-java-generics is worth a read

Comment: You should be able to define common behavior by configuring superclass and then using component configuration inheritance. Have you tried it?

Comment: So all these inherit from the super class (DaoClass) is the .close() method, otherwise they are different, so the baeldung.com method doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: Configuring superclass and using component configuration inheritance?  I can't find anything about that.  I wanted to avoid separate configuration for each interface though.